# Spinner with dynamic list is not working

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

```
_doctorSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.input_doctor);
final ArrayList<String> docList = new ArrayList<String>();
DataUtil.getDoctorList(this.getApplicationContext(), new ServerCallBack() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(JSONObject result) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String result) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(JSONArray result) {
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("Select Doctor");
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                    list.add(result.getString(i));
                }
                docList.addAll(list);
            } catch (JSONException e) {

            }
        }
    });

    final ArrayAdapter<String> docAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, docList);
    docAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    docAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    _doctorSpinner.setAdapter(docAdapter);
    _doctorSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            System.out.println(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

In the above code i am getting a list of strings from server and populating  in the spinner. When the activity is loaded i am unable to see the first item in the list("Select a doctor"). But when i click on spinner, i could see the items and select. Again then selected item is not visible as selected. Could anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you spinner background color doesn't match you `textColor`. Try inflating your own layout instead of using the default one.

Answer (score 1):

```
        _doctorSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.input_doctor);
    final ArrayList<String> docList = new ArrayList<String>();
    DataUtil.getDoctorList(this.getApplicationContext(), new ServerCallBack() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(JSONObject result) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String result) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(JSONArray result) {
                ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                list.add("Select Doctor");
                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                        list.add(result.getString(i));
                    }
                    docList.addAll(list);
final ArrayAdapter<String> docAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, docList);
        docAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        docAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        _doctorSpinner.setAdapter(docAdapter);
        _doctorSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                System.out.println(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
                } catch (JSONException e) {

                }
            }
        });
```

webservice call work in background thread so ypou get list size zero when u set adapter so inialize and setadapter when call finish

Comment: Thanks. It worked but i had to pass PatientSignupActivity.super.getBaseContext() insteadof this to ArrayAdapter constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Call `notifyDataSetChanged();` after your data is added to the list.

```
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(JSONArray result) {
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("Select Doctor");
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                    list.add(result.getString(i));
                }
                docList.addAll(list);

                if (null != docAdapter)
                        docAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            } catch (JSONException e) {

            }
        }
```

**EDIT :**

My bad I read the question incorrectly. 
If you cannot see the text inside your spinner try this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> docAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, docList);
```

And I don't believe you need to use `docAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);`